# Sending GET and POST methods from server to client side (JavaFX)

Tags: javafx, servlets

I have a simple login servlet which checks the email and password if the user is registered or not , now I'm trying to work on a JavaFX app which does the same job by reading from the servlet the information, my servlet works perfect but I don't know how to interact with my servlet from JavaFX , how can I send a response from the servlet to JavaFX ? I've searched a lot but couldn't find anything

Here's my servlet :

```
import java.io.*;
import java.security.Principal;
import java.util.Date;
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;

import jakarta.servlet.RequestDispatcher;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletConfig;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletContext;
import jakarta.servlet.ServletException;
import jakarta.servlet.annotation.WebServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServlet;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletRequest;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpServletResponse;
import jakarta.servlet.http.HttpSession;

@WebServlet("/HelloServlet")
public class HelloServlet extends HttpServlet {
//int attempts = 3;
Date date;
/**
 *
 */
private static final long serialVersionUID = -5498866193863633001L;

/**
 * HashMap to store all users credentials
 */
private final Map<String, String> credentialsPairs = new HashMap<>();

@Override
public void init(ServletConfig config) throws ServletException {
    String delimiter = ",";
    String line = "";

    /**
     * Credentials file will be there in WEB-INF directory as it provide secured
     * access only.
     */
    String credentialFile = "/WEB-INF/accounts.txt";

    /**
     * Read the file and prepare Map with username as key and password as value We
     * have put this code in init method as it is called once only that will avoid
     * overhead of iterating values from file for each request
     */
    InputStream is = null;
    InputStreamReader isr = null;
    BufferedReader br = null;

    ServletContext context = config.getServletContext();

    try {
        /**
         * Open stream of file
         */
        is = context.getResourceAsStream(credentialFile);
        if (is != null) {
            /**
             * Read the file line by line and store email as a key and password as value
             */
            isr = new InputStreamReader(is);
            br = new BufferedReader(isr);
            while ((line = br.readLine()) != null) {
                String[] credentials = line.split(delimiter);
                // credentials[0] is email and credentials[1] is password
                credentialsPairs.put(credentials[0], credentials[1]);
            }
        }
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    } finally {
        try {
            if (br != null) {
                br.close();
            }
            if (isr != null) {
                isr.close();
            }
            if (is != null) {
                is.close();
            }
        } catch (IOException e) {
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}

public void service(HttpServletRequest request, HttpServletResponse response) throws 
IOException, ServletException {
    /**
     * Get user entered credentials
     */
    String userEmail = request.getParameter("email");
    String userPassword = request.getParameter("password");
    PrintWriter out = response.getWriter();

    boolean isValidUser = false;

    /**
     * Get value from Map for user entered email address.
     */
    String password = credentialsPairs.get(userEmail);

    /**
     * If User with entered email address found then we will get password for that
     * user
     */
    if (password != null) {
        /**
         * Compare password entered by user with one that is retrieved from file
         */
        if (password.equals(userPassword)) {
            isValidUser = true;
        }
        }
    }
    
    HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        if (isValidUser) {
            //HttpSession session = request.getSession();
            session.setAttribute("email", userEmail);
            //request.getRequestDispatcher("welcome.jsp").include(request, response);
            response.sendRedirect("welcome.jsp");
            //response.setContentType("text/html");
            //response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_FOUND,"Hello");
        }
        else {
            int loginAttempt;
            if (session.getAttribute("loginCount") == null)
            {
                session.setAttribute("loginCount", 0);
                loginAttempt = 0;
            }
            else
            {
                loginAttempt = (Integer) session.getAttribute("loginCount");
            }

            //this is 3 attempt counting from 0,1,2
            if (loginAttempt >= 2 )
            {
                long lastAccessedTime = session.getLastAccessedTime();
                date = new Date();
                long currentTime = date.getTime();
                long timeDiff = currentTime - lastAccessedTime;
                // 20 minutes in milliseconds
                if (timeDiff >= 1200000)
                {
                    //invalidate user session, so they can try again
                    session.invalidate();
                }
                else
                {
                    // Error message
                    session.setAttribute("message","You have exceeded the 3 failed login 
 attempt. Please try loggin in in 20 minutes.");
                    //request.getRequestDispatcher("fail.jsp");
                    out.println("You have exceeded the 3 failed login attempt. Please 
 try loggin in in 20 minutes.");
                }
            }
            else
            {
                loginAttempt++;
                int allowLogin = 3-loginAttempt;
                session.setAttribute("message","loginAttempt= "+loginAttempt+". Invalid 
 username or password. You have "+allowLogin+" attempts remaining. Please try again!");
                out.println("Invalid email or password , please try again");
                final String message = "The requested page not found";
                response.sendError(HttpServletResponse.SC_NOT_FOUND,message);
            }
            session.setAttribute("loginCount",loginAttempt);
        }
}

public void destroy() {
    /**
     * Free up the map
     */
    credentialsPairs.clear();
}
}
```

Here's my JavaFX code :

```
import javafx.application.Application;
import javafx.fxml.FXMLLoader;
import javafx.geometry.Insets;
import javafx.geometry.Pos;
import javafx.scene.Scene;
import javafx.scene.control.Button;
import javafx.scene.control.ComboBox;
import javafx.scene.control.Label;
import javafx.scene.control.TextField;
import javafx.scene.layout.BorderPane;
import javafx.scene.layout.HBox;
import javafx.scene.layout.VBox;
import javafx.stage.Stage;

import java.io.BufferedReader;
import java.io.DataOutputStream;
import java.io.IOException;
import java.io.InputStreamReader;
import java.net.HttpURLConnection;
import java.net.URL;


public class HelloApplication extends Application {
    TextField tName;
    TextField tPassword;
    ComboBox comboBox;
    Button login;
    VBox vBox;
    BorderPane borderPane;
    URL url = null;
    HttpURLConnection con = null;
    int flag =0;
    @Override
    public void start(Stage stage) throws IOException {
        stage.setTitle("login Page");
        stage.setResizable(false);
        setDesign();
        comboBox.setOnAction(e->{
            if(comboBox.getSelectionModel().isSelected(0)){
                flag =0;

            }else if (comboBox.getSelectionModel().isSelected(1)){
                flag =1;
            }
        });
        login.setOnAction(e->{
            if(flag==0){
                try {
                    System.out.println("get");
                    String name =tName.getText();
                    String password =tPassword.getText();
                    url = new URL("http://localhost:8080/try8_war_exploded/login? 
   email="+name+"&password="+password);
                    con = (HttpURLConnection)url.openConnection();
                    con.setRequestMethod("GET");
                    con.setRequestProperty("Content-Type","text/html");
                    con.setConnectTimeout(5000);
                    con.setReadTimeout(5000);

                } catch(Exception c) {
                    c.printStackTrace();
                }
            }
            else {
                
            }

            int status = 0;
            StringBuffer data = new StringBuffer();
            try {
                status = con.getResponseCode();
                if(status > 299) {
                    System.out.println("error "+status);
                    System.out.println(con.getErrorStream());
                    return;
                }
                BufferedReader in = new BufferedReader(new 
        InputStreamReader(con.getInputStream()));
                String str = null;
                while((str=in.readLine()) != null) data.append(str);
                System.out.println("here");
                System.out.println(str);
                in.close();
                con.disconnect();
            } catch(Exception c) {
                c.printStackTrace();
            }
        });

        Scene scene =new Scene(borderPane,350,180);
        stage.setScene(scene);
        stage.show();
    }

    public void setDesign(){
        borderPane = new BorderPane();
        borderPane.setPadding(new Insets(20,20,20,20));

        vBox = new VBox(10);
        vBox.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        HBox hBox1 =new HBox(5);
        hBox1.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);
        HBox hBox2 =new HBox(5);
        hBox2.setAlignment(Pos.CENTER);

        Label label1= new Label("E-mail");
        tName = new TextField();
        tName.setMaxWidth(150);
        hBox1.getChildren().addAll(label1,tName);
        Label label2= new Label("Password");
        tPassword = new TextField();
        tPassword.setMaxWidth(150);
        hBox2.getChildren().addAll(label2,tPassword);

        comboBox = new ComboBox();
        comboBox.getItems().add("Get");
        comboBox.getItems().add("Post");
        comboBox.getSelectionModel().selectFirst();
        login = new Button("Login");
        vBox.getChildren().addAll(hBox1,hBox2,comboBox,login);
        borderPane.setTop(vBox);
    }
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        launch();
    }
 }
```

I'm posting the entire codes so that everything is clear

Comment: would be a bit helpful if you share some content from "welcome.jsp"